# Kotlin - Create directory in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() on Android 10+

Tags: android, kotlin, directory, storage, mkdir

This has been asked before but I am unable to find an answer that works well for me.

I have an app in which, at first run, I need to create some directories and files in those directories.

What I have done so far works well on Android 5 to 9.
To my surprise, it does no work on Android 10+ since getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated.

This is what I am doing so far:

```
if(isFirstRun)
{
    Log.i("MyApp","ServerWizardActivity > createNecesaryFoldersFiles > isFirstRun")

    val absoluteExternalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
    val appDirectory = File("${absoluteExternalStorageDirectory}/MyApp/")
    val picturesDirectory = File("${absoluteExternalStorageDirectory}/Pictures/")

    val fullPath: String? = "${absoluteExternalStorageDirectory}/MyApp/${jsonFileName}"
    var dataFile = File(fullPath)

    if (!appDirectory .exists())
    {
        Log.i("MyApp","ServerWizardActivity > createNecesaryFoldersFiles > appDirectory")

        appDirectory .mkdir()
    }

    if (!picturesDirectory.exists())
    {
        Log.i("MyApp","ServerWizardActivity > createNecesaryFoldersFiles > picturesDirectory")

        picturesDirectory.mkdir()
    }

    if(!dataFile.exists())
    {
        Log.i("MyApp","ServerWizardActivity > createNecesaryFoldersFiles > dataFile")

        dataFile.createNewFile()
    }
}
else
{
    Log.i("MyApp","ServerWizardActivity > createNecesaryFoldersFiles > isNotFirstRun")
}
```

So far so good.
However, I need to create a directory directly on the Device Storage, on the same level with DCIM, Pictures, Documents and Downloads so that I can make it consistent with Android 5-9 version and the iOS version of the app.

I tried the code below for Android 10+ and it works but I can only create a directory in one of the directories in Environment (in this case, the Pictures directory).
Is there any way to bypass? I don't want to change the entire app structure because of this.

```
if(isFirstRun)
    {
        val resolver = contentResolver
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/MyApp"
        )
        val path = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues).toString()
        val folder = File(path)
        val isCreated = folder.exists()

        if (!isCreated)
        {
            folder.mkdirs()
        }
    }
```

Oh, and soi far I have these in my Android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
</application>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the *user* decide where on the *user's* device (or in the *user's* chosen cloud storage provider) that your app should store the *user's* content.

Comment: @CommonsWare - This is not up to me. And since the app has to work like the iOS version, I would have to change that one as well and that is not an option.

Comment: The user, outside of your app, could create a directory off of external storage root, but there is no way (other than via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) for the user to grant you access to that directory. If your app will be distributed through the Play Store, your `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` approach will not work starting later this year, and it is highly unlikely that Google will grant you a waiver to use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the info. Not sure if the app will go through PlayStore (the iOS version is hosted in house). I'll try to see how I can change the structure without affecting the functionality too much.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code it will help you to create a test directory inside document directory.

```
//Make sure don't forget to ask runtime permission of read/write file
private fun writeFile(fileData: String, fileName: String) {
val dir = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
            .toString() + "/" + "test"
    )
} else {
    File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString() + "/${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS}/" + "test"
    )
}
dir.apply {
    if (!this.exists()) this.mkdir()
    File(this, "$fileName.txt").apply {
        if (!this.exists()) this.createNewFile()
        FileOutputStream(this).apply {
            write(fileData.toByteArray())
            close()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try. The problem is I need the directory created on level up, on the same level as DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, not inside it. The entire app was designed like that at first.

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting this error: "java.io.IOException: No such file or directory" when running the app on my phone. And for some reason I can't create A10 AVDs to test it on since I keep getting BSODs on run...